# On searching for commit in VSTS produces Error: VCErrorCommitNotFound

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am using VSCode IDE for anuglarjs project and source code repository is VSTS Git repository. I have also installed the Git History plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory) to see the commit history details for each committed file.

I see a difference in commit history for a file between the VSTS git master branch and the Git History plugin interface master branch.

Actually the commit history shown in the Git History view is the latest and correct one but it seems VSTS commit history has ignored it.

Can anyone help me to know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On double checking the Git history in VSCode editor, I found that it was in my local master branch (red color indication) and not yet committed into the remote master branch. It was showing an indication of one staged change in the bottom section of the VSCode editor. I committed the changes into the remote master branch and then found the missing commit history in the VSTS Git repository.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.